# Oracle math Calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, math, oracle-apex

I need help with a math problem.  The code works but I am not receiving the correct answer and I am sure it has everything to do with the syntax.  Here goes.

```
round((length1 + length2)/kilometer) *1000,2) per_km
```

This code works fine but the answer I receive is incorrect.  The physical Math problem looks like this `3.6(L1) + 10.2(L2) / 174.44(Kilometer) * 1000 = 9.447(correct answer)` easily calculated with a calculator. When I use the above code my answer is `12.96`.

The calculated per row of an ID.  Should I use an `over(partition by ID)` will this fix the issue?  Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you know of good Oracle tutorial concerning math problems please feel free to send the link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you not want it calculated per row?  Can you post query/sample data?

Comment: Please check the parenthesis in both posted expressions as they differ. Which one is correct?  Also what are the data types of each field involved?

Comment: My calculator doesn't agree with your answer...  3.6 + 10.2 = 13.8.  13.8/ 174.44 = 0.07911.  0.07911 * 1000 = 79.11.  That doesn't match either answer so either the formula is not what you put here or the values are not what you put here.

Comment: You've got 3 closing parenthesis and 2 open.. so that's something.

Comment: what are the data types of the variables used?

Comment: Goat CO -Yes. I also believe the closed parenthesis may be the problem  unfortunately, I do not understand the "open" and "closed" parenthesis. I'm still a newbie. PM 77-1 - The second expression is correct. (Number) Justin, you are correct sorry! The correct answer would be 79.11 ty.

Comment: Your question doesn't have any SQL so your "OVER PARTITION BY" is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is

round((length1 + length2)/kilometer *1000,2) per_km

To confirm I did...

select round((3.6 + 10.2) / 174.44 * 1000, 2) from dual;

This gives an answer of 79.11 as per your last comment.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Shaun can I use over by partition to stop duplicates?

Comment: sorry not familiar with the analytic functions so cant help you on that one.